# When my controller function loads a view, the URL has the controller name and function still in the URL. How can I get rid of this?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Basically my function checks to see if something is in a database. If it's found it returns true and carries on to the next view. However, if it returns false it reloads the home.php view but it seems to still leave URI segments in the URL...

```
example:
www.example.com/index.php/home/checkSearchFields
```

How to I get it to get rid of the 'home/checkSearchFields'?

Thanks for your help.

**home.php (view)**

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    function getStates(value) {
        $.post(base_url + "/buildings/getstates.php",{partialState:value},function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
    }

    function myFunction(){
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var str = target.innerHTML;
        console.log(str);
        document.getElementById("stateSearch").value = str ;
        $( "#results" ).empty();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<h1>Room Finder</h1>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('home/checkSearchFields'); ?>

    <div class="searchfield">

        Building: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="building" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)" id="stateSearch" autocomplete="off"/>

    </div><!-- closes searchfield -->
    <div class="searchfield">

        Room #: <br/>
        <input type="text" name="roomNum" autocomplete="off"/><br/>

    </div><!-- closes searchfield -->
    <div class="submit">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

    </div><!-- closes submit -->

</form>

<div id="results"></div>
```

**home.php (Controller)**

```
class home extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home');
}

public function checkSearchFields(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('building', 'Building', 'required|callback_verifyBuilding');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('roomNum', 'RoomNum', 'required');

    $roomNumber = $this->session->userdata('roomNumber'); // going to be checked to see if null

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $this->load->view('home');
    }else{
        $this->load->view('worked');
    }


}



public function verifyBuilding(){

    $buildings = $this->input->post('building');
    $roomNum = $this->input->post('roomNum');

    $this->load->model('BuildingModel');

    if($this->BuildingModel->userSearch($buildings, $roomNum)){
        return true;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyBuilding', 'Incorrect Building Name or Room Number... Please try again...');
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

**buildingmodel.php (Model)**

```
class BuildingModel extends CI_Model{
public function userSearch($buildings, $roomNum){


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('buildings');
    $this->db->where('buildingName', $buildings);

    $query = $this->db->get();




    if($query->num_rows() == 1){

        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $buildingID = $row['buildingID'];
            $buildingName = $row['buildingName'];
            $buildingLocation = $row['buildingLocation'];
            $imagePath = $row['imagePath'];
        }

        $userSearch = array(
               'buildingID' => $buildingID,
               'buildingName' => $buildingName,
               'buildingLocation' => $buildingLocation,
               'imagePath' => $imagePath,
           );

        $this->session->set_userdata($userSearch);
        //query DB for the room numbers


            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('rooms');
            $this->db->where('buildingID', $buildingID);
            $this->db->where('roomNumber', $roomNum);

            $query2 = $this->db->get();

            if($query2->num_rows() == 1){

                foreach($query2->result_array() as $row)
                    {
                        $roomID = $row['roomID'];
                        $roomNumber = $row['roomNumber'];
                        $roomCode = $row['roomCode'];
                        $office = $row['office'];
                        $location = $row['location'];
                        $roomName = $row['roomName'];
                    }

                    $userSearch = array(
                           'roomID' => $roomID,
                           'roomNumber' => $roomNumber,
                           'roomCode' => $roomCode,
                           'office' => $office,
                           'location' => $location,
                           'roomName' => $roomName,
                       );
                    $this->session->set_userdata($userSearch);
            }


        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What scripts, and how are they not working?

Comment: @ethan just added my code into the question

Comment: Okay i've got the scripts working now. I added;

var base_url = window.location.origin;

and also added it to the php file that was being called since it was looking for it after the long URL

Answer (score 0):

As you said, it just loads the view. Which view is loaded, has nothing to do with how the URL looks like.

You could replace this:

```
 if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
    $this->load->view('home');
}else{
    $this->load->view('worked');
}
```

with this:

```
 if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
    redirect('home');
}else{
    $this->load->view('worked');
}
```

When it fails, it redirects you to the homepage.